# How to get the UID of a user and set a value to from my FireRecyclerAdapter with a button?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set a value of '1' or '0' to my list of users on a node named 'Blocked Users' in Firebase. However, I'm only retrieving the UID of the account that is logged in on the app I'm currently using instead of the ones on the list:

```html
{
  "Blocked Users" : {
    "HnREoOYynjVfPlTQKCt5744SzAt1" : 1
  },
  "User Location" : {
    "latitude" : 
    "longitude" : 
  },
  "Users" : {
    "RCX2HZXIwlSmMHFgDytf1DgZBgi2" : {
      "Alert Level" : 
      "Emergency Type" :
      "address" : ,
      "emergencyNum" : 
      "name" : 
      "phoneNum" : 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the UID in 'Users', the ones on the RecyclerView, not the current user in the app. Here's how I'm doing so far:

My adapter:

```
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainData model) {
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
        holder.phoneNum.setText(model.getPhoneNum());



    }


    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    Context context;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainData> mainDataFirebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        super(mainDataFirebaseRecyclerOptions);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            CircleImageView image;
            TextView name, address, phoneNum;
            ToggleButton toggleButton;


        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressText);
            phoneNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberText);


            itemView.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            blockUser();

                }
            });

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        unblockUser();

                }
            });


        }
    }


    private void blockUser() {


                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blocked Users").child(uid);

                reference.setValue(1)
                        .addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<Void>) unused -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "User Blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

    }

    private void unblockUser(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blocked Users").child(uid);
        reference.setValue(0)
                .addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<Void>) unused -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "User Unblocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, "Failed"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }

}
```

RecyclerView Activity:

```
public class Report extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MainAdapter mainAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainData> mainDataFirebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainData>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"), MainData.class)
                .build();



        mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(mainDataFirebaseRecyclerOptions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mainAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mainAdapter.stopListening();
    }
```

The layout for the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:padding="15dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nameText"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/addressText"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/numberText"
            android:text="Emergency Number"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addressText"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-76dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberText"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_error"
            android:text="Revoke Access"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-76dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberText"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:text="Grant Access"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to know if what I am doing so far is the correct way of making this possible or not.

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262670/how-to-get-the-key-from-the-reference-of-child-in-firebase) All you have to do is get the key with the position in the adapter as in this answer and it will give you the id of the users on this adapter.

Comment: Where should I place the button and the events that comes with it in the adapter?

Comment: [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/) I think you have a class like here.
`String key = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();` I hope you can do this with the position in the onBindViewHolder when the button is clicked (I'm talking about the button you already have).

Comment: Is any of the `.setValue(0)` or  `.setValue(1)` operations working?

Comment: It's working, but it's retrieving the current user that's logged in the app installed. Instead of the user's UID saved in the database